# Compiler Error Message: CS1502

Tags: asp.net, linq

For the below linq query I added

```
w = document.tblTransmittalls.Select(dx => dx.tblFiles)
```

Field and also for the below function I added "theDocument.w" argument but i have error and it shows me:

```
IEnumerable<System.Data.Linq.EntitySet<tblFile>>
```

While I like to be like other arguments: `IEnumerable<tblFile> w`
I do not know what happened.

> Compiler Error Message: CS1502

Before adding "theDocument.w" argument to my function I had not error.

```
private void DisplayDocument()
{
    var documents =
      from document in _DataContext.tblDocuments
      where document.DocId == _DocID
      select new
      {
          DocId = document.DocId,
          Title = document.TITLE,
          DocNo = document.DocumentNo,
          Originator = document.Originator,
          Type = document.Document_Type,
          Unit = document.Unit,
          MaterialCode = document.EQ_IN_Identify_Material_Code,
          Transmittals = document.tblTransmittalls.Select(dt => dt.tbltransmittalNo),
          x = document.tblTransmittalls.Select(dp => dp.tblDocTranstoCons.tblTranstoCon),
          //Authors = book.BookAuthors.Select(bookAuthor => bookAuthor.AuthorObject),
          y = document.tblTransmittalls,
          z = document.tblTransmittalls.Select(dp => dp.tblDocTranstoCons),
          w = document.tblTransmittalls.Select(dx => dx.tblFiles)
      }

DisplayTransmittals(theDocument.Transmittals, theDocument.x, theDocument.DocId, theDocument.y, theDocument.z, theDocument.w);


private void DisplayTransmittals(IEnumerable<tbltransmittalNo> transmittals, IEnumerable<tblTranstoCon> x, int d,
    IEnumerable<tblTransmittall> y, IEnumerable<tblDocTranstoCon> z, IEnumerable<tblFile> w)
{
    Transmittallistfortest transmittalList = (Transmittallistfortest)DetailsView1.FindControl("Transmittallistfortest1");
    GridView g3 = transmittalList.FindControl("GridViewTtransmittals") as GridView;
    transmittalList.Transmittals = transmittals;
    transmittalList.Doc = d;
    transmittalList.Transmittaltocons = x;
    transmittalList.DocTranstoCons = z;
    transmittalList.tblTransmittall = y;
    transmittalList.Efiles = w;
    transmittalList.DataBind();

}
```

Comment: In future, please give the actual error *message*, not just the error code.

Answer (score 0):

Googling your error code returns [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b66k5sz9%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) which says that it is the code for `The best overloaded method match for 'declaration' has some invalid arguments` errors.

Based on that and the result of adding `theDocument.w` causing an error, it sounds like `theDocument.w` is not of type `IEnumerable<tblFile>`.